Kestrel override certificate settings from appsetting.development.json
I have this Kestrel settings in appsetting.json
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:7514"
    },
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:7513"
      "Certificate": {
        "Path": "myCert.pfx",
        "Password": "somePassword"
      }
    }
  }
},

and have this in appsetting.development.json
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:7514"
    },
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:7515"
      }
    }
}

When in development mode, it uses the correct port from development appsetting, but still expects the certificate, how do I override that settings so it doesn't need the certificate
This is the setup
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions() { ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory, Args = args, ApplicationName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName };
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);
builder.Host.UseWindowsService(); 


If you want to use https it must need the certificate, it use the certificate to secure the connection between the client and server. Without using it, we couldn't use the tls connection between client and server.
If you don't want to set the certificate for the https, you could remove the https part just use http for testing.

Removing https from development app settings does nothing, still crashing on certificate. If I remove certificate from main app setting, it runs in stand alone mode, which I want it to do but take the settings from development app settings
